# how to declare an object in javascript es6 class constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I declared a property in class constructor and accessing through methods, which is declared as 'static', with 'this' and it is not accessible. How to get access to constructor (class) variables inside static methods?

```
export class Reporter {
    constructor() {
        this.jsonReports = path.join(process.cwd(), "/reports/json")

        this.cucumberReporterOptions = {
            jsonFile: targetJson,
            output: htmlReports + "/cucumber_reporter.html",
            reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
            theme: "bootstrap",
        }
    }

    static createHTMLReport() {
        try {
            reporter.generate(this.cucumberReporterOptions);
        } catch (err) {

        }
    }
}
```

Updated:

As per "@CodingIntrigue", I have done like this in 'reporter.js' file and called the method as Reporter.createHTMLReport() in my config file and its working as expected. But not sure if this is best practice.

```
const jsonReports = path.join(process.cwd(), "/reports/json")

const cucumberReporterOptions = {
    jsonFile: targetJson,
    output: htmlReports + "/cucumber_reporter.html",
    reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
    theme: "bootstrap",
}

export class Reporter {
    static createHTMLReport() {
        try {
            reporter.generate(cucumberReporterOptions);
        } catch (err) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't, that's not what static methods are for.

Comment: You can't, that's why the method is static, there is no access to instance members.

Comment: `Reporter` doesn't sound like it should be a `class` at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091167/es6-classes-updating-static-properties

Comment: @CodingIntrigue, I get it. If so, whats your suggestion. because I am using a protractor cucumber framework for my testing project and I need to inform this instruction in the config file which will be invoked at the start of execution.

Comment: @mmar Can you link the docs of your framework about this? I really can't believe it requires a `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue using `class` syntax, you can just make `jsonReports` and `cucubmerReporterOptions` static properties too:

```
export class Reporter {
    static createHTMLReport() {
        try {
            reporter.generate(Reporter.cucumberReporterOptions);
        } catch (err) {

        }
    }
}

Reporter.jsonReports = path.join(process.cwd(), "/reports/json")

Reporter.cucumberReporterOptions = {
    jsonFile: targetJson,
    output: htmlReports + "/cucumber_reporter.html",
    reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
    theme: "bootstrap",
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the solution I have done as per your suggestion and its working too. But not sure if this could be a good practice to follow.

Comment: That practice is fine. You should post your code in an answer

Comment: @CodingIntrigue Using a `class` without a constructor, without instance properties, without any instance methods, is *not* a "fine practice".

Comment: @Bergi I did say in the comments above that it shouldn't be a `class` at all, but I was going on the possibly incorrect assumption that not *everything* was going to be static in the class